# Why cross-compiling for ARM fails in ./configure?

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling, autoconf, swi-prolog

I know the question is vague, but I didn't quite know how to express what I'm facing here: I'm trying to cross-compile an implementation of Prolog (particularly SWI-Prolog) from the [sources](http://swi-prolog.org/build/unix.html). They use the GNU-Autoconf tools (to which I'm a complete beginner) to build the sources, so I supposed I could set the `--host` and `--build` triplets to allow for ARM cross-compilation, but it didn't work. This is the command I issued:

```
$ ./configure --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --host=arm-linux-gnueabi

(... lots of checks ...)

checking for clock_gettime in -lrt... yes
checking for clock_gettime... yes
checking for pthread support for cpu clocks... configure: error: in `(...)/pl-6.6.5/src':
configure: error: cannot run test program while cross compiling
See `config.log' for more details
```

(The complete output is pasted [here](http://pastebin.com/xfWPG2Bf))

I've checked the [*config.log* file](http://pastebin.com/6Znqs9QT), but I am unable to understand what's exactly missing. I understand that at this stage, there might be several missing libraries or errors, but I'm unable to understand where to start from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The output of `configure` says:

```
checking for pthread support for cpu clocks... configure: error: in `(...)/pl-6.6.5/src':
configure: error: cannot run test program while cross compiling
```

What this probably means is that somewhere in `configure.ac` there's a call to the macro `AC_TRY_RUN` or something like it.  This macro basically compiles an executable and executes it, trying to find out more details.  Calling this macro won't work when cross compiling, since the *build* and *host* architecture differ.  From your paste, there seems to be another one that doesn't cause `configure` to fail:

```
checking whether mutex support recursive locking... ./configure: line 7307: ./conftest: cannot execute binary file
```

IMHO package maintainers should be notified that their package won't cross compile (unless they specifically say that it won't in the `README` or other documentation).

In order to get it to cross compile, you have to figure out the "right" answers of the `AC_TRY_RUN` tests for your platform and find a way to integrate them into `configure.ac`, essentially patching `configure.ac`.  The package maintainers might be able to assist with this task also.

I suppose you could also use something like [Scratchbox2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scratchbox2) if it's available for your device.

Comment: This is good advice.  Also, there maybe configure options that will avoid a check.  For example `--with-package` or `--without-package`.  You should run `./configure --help` to see.  Ie, you can try to avoid the `AC_TRY_RUN` macro with options.  Another way is to patch the configure to *short-circuit* to your platforms desired configuration.  The same patch will probably apply versus upgrade paths.

Answer (score 1):

I tried setting "cross-compile" option in configure file to yes.
The evaluation logic which interprets if you are cross-compiling is flaky. It hangs in balance between maybe and yes.
Aborts compilation as soon as it gets to maybe stage.

```
#
# Initializations.
#
ac_default_prefix=/usr/local
ac_config_libobj_dir=.
cross_compiling=**yes**
subdirs=
MFLAGS=
MAKEFLAGS=
SHELL=${CONFIG_SHELL-/bin/sh}
```

I sourced my environment setup script for toolchain before configuring.
. /usr/local/

This populates the CC and CXX and other env var's.
Then try configuring with below options.

./configure --host=x86_64 --target=armv7a --build=armv7 --prefix=/home/kamal/dmalloc-5.5.2/bld CXXFLAGS=-fPIC CFLAGS=-fPIC --enable-threads --disable-shlib --enable-cxx

Note: I had to undef strdup in dmalloc.h over strdup declaration, i.e.

```
#undef strdup
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Try newer version of package you want crosscompile.